# variable linked in page URL, how-to and are spaces okay?

Tags: php, html

3 quick questions:

I want to create one page "view_build.php" which, when opened, takes a variable from the URL contained within it, and displays unique information for that 'build'. For example

```
<a href="view_build.php?buildname=$row[0]">$row[0]</a>
```

The above is a link to a page called view_build.php?buildname=VARIABLE

Does the .php file contain the variable in a $_GET array, JUST from me including a variable name in the html link?

And if so, is it okay if there are spaces in it? For example:

```
view_build.php?buildname=Dual Zoren
```

Lastly, how do I include more than one variable in the URL? What is the syntax?

Thanks so much!
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the .php file contain the variable in a $_GET array, JUST from me including a variable name in the html link?

Yes. To elaborate, if you call `view_build.php` via an HTTP request with the URL query parameters `foo=bar`, then within that script, you can access `$_GET['foo']` which will have the value `bar`.

> is it okay if there are spaces in it?

No, they should be URL encoded. See http://php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php

For example

```
<a href="view_build.php?buildname=<?= urlencode($row[0]) ?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($row[0]) ?></a>
```

> Lastly, how do I include more than one variable in the URL? What is the syntax?

URL query parameters are separated by the `&` character, eg

```
view_build.php?buildname=Dual+Zoren&foo=1&bar=2
```